# Get object values without looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have following object:

```
var input = {
  'foo': 2,
  'bar': 6,
  'baz': 4
};
```

Is it possible to get values from this object without looping it ?

It is possible to use `jQuery`.

Expected result:

```
var output = [2, 6, 4];
```

Comment: Do you know objects keys? Are they static?

Comment: Is it ok if under-the-hood jQuery will use loops?

Comment: A loop is always going to be necessary on some level

Comment: Underscore JS has a function for that: http://underscorejs.org/#values

Comment: If the keys are dynamic (i.e., unknown) then there is no way to do this without a loop. Note also that object properties do not have an inherent order, so there's no way to guarantee the output array would have the values in the order you show. (You can extract the keys from an object and sort them and then produce the final output based on that, but the output you showed isn't based on alphabetic order, so...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var arr = $.map(input,function(v){
 return v;
});
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/CPM4M/

Comment: Ah, beat be by a couple secs.

Comment: that's still a loop. an unefficient one, what's more

Answer (score 8):

This is simply not possible without a loop. There's no `Object.values()` method (yet) to complement [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Until then you're basically "stuck" with the below construct:

```
var values = [];

for (var k in input) {
  if (input.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
    values.push(input[k]);
  }
}
```

Or, in modern browsers (but of course still using a loop and an anonymous function call):

```
var values = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(input).map(function(key) {
    return input[key];
});
```

Comment: Now there is Object.values() but it's still at its experimental stage with Google chrome 51.0 and Firefox 47 supporting the function. Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values

Comment: `Object.values()` is now standard in all latest browsers (including mobile), with the exception of the obsolete IE (all versions).

Answer (score 4):

You can get values from this object without looping using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) method like:

```
var output = Object.values( input );
console.log( output );  // [2, 6, 4]
```

**DEMO:**

```js
var input = {
  'foo': 2,
  'bar': 6,
  'baz': 4
};

var output = Object.values( input );
console.log( output );
```

**PLEASE NOTE:**

> **This is an experimental technology**
>
> Because this technology's specification has not stabilized, check the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values#Browser_compatibility) for usage in various browsers. Also note that the syntax and behavior of an experimental technology is subject to change in future versions of browsers as the specification changes.

So, currently it supports Chrome & Firefox only.

Comment: If the keys are dynamic, how do you know how many there are to hardcode the indices?

Comment: The esiest way.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you want without loop . here my solution

```
JSON.stringify( input ).replace(/"(.*?)"\:|\{|\}/g,'' ).split(',')
```

it print `[2, 6, 4]` . I didn't test for other json values

Comment: This regex only works on key-value pairs where the value is not quoted because it greedily absorbs values as well. So it will work with the OP's example but it won't generalize.

Answer (score -2):

```
var input = {
  'foo': 2,
  'bar': 6,
  'baz': 4
};
var newArr = new Array;
$.each(input,function(key,value) {
    newArr.push(value);
});
alert(newArr)
```

Comment: `each` is still a loop.

Comment: The this is impossible without a loop